# What is the area of the Pokémon Moon logo?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Recently, the seventh generation of Pokémon games — Pokémon Sun and Moon — were announced. Along with it came the new logo symbols, of which the Moon logo is of particular interest:

[image: The Pokémon Moon logo.]

Consider the symbol at the right, a high-resolution version of which is shown below (from [here](http://nicholas-checchia.deviantart.com/art/Pokemon-Moon-Logo-5000x5000-593943926)):

[image: The symbol from the Pokémon Moon logo.]

All the borders in this logo are created from circular arcs. Suppose the large circle that the logo was "carved out of" was radius 1; how would you figure out the exact area of this rounded figure using only a straightedge with ruler markings on it (that can measure any straight-line distance between two given points)? In particular, you're not given the radii or centers of curvature of any of the arcs.

Comment: Can you use the ruler to measure curves, e.g. to measure the diameter of the circle?  Can you make extra marks on the diagram and measure to/from those?

Comment: What do you mean by "measure curves"? You can't use it to measure the _length_ of a curve, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: What is the definition of "exact"? I'm asking because "measurements" in the real world always have some precision. Or we have to assume that the "measurements" are with infinite precision?

Comment: @kamenf The latter. The measurements you get with the straightedge can be used as infinitely precise for the theory of this problem.

Comment: @2012rcampion You can't measure the diameter of the circle unless you have a basis for drawing two points exactly opposite each other.

Comment: @2012rcampion Also, the diameter of the large circle is given as 2 (because its radius is 1). All the measurements your ruler gives are relative to that diameter.

Comment: @2012rcampion But yes, you can make extra marks, as long as you can construct them properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct them properly?"  If I just want to mark three arbitrary points (e.g. to construct a triangle whose circumcircle is one of the circular arcs), is that allowed?  Also, can we assume the logo is symmetric?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, you can mark three arbitrary points on a circle and measure their distances. But you're not allowed a construct a point "whose distance is _________ from another point".

Comment: Basically, when marking new points, all the restrictions of Euclidean constructions apply.

Comment: Also, the logo doesn't appear to _actually_ be symmetric on closer inspection. I don't think the assumption really matters, though.

Comment: Should the question not be on the math overflowing website?

Comment: I presented it as a math puzzle because it's not a problem that can be solved just by applying a formula and doing some calculations — part of the problem is finding out what those calculations are, and there's not really an obvious, conventional way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short:

> I assume we can do calculations. So, we can calculate radius of any circle by inscribing arbitrary triangle in it. Let say it is $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ which we can measure, and angles $\alpha,\;\beta$ and $\gamma$ which we may calculate form the sides:
>
>   $$\cos(\alpha)\;=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$
>
>  and radius R is:
>
>  $$R\;=\frac a{2\sin(\alpha)}$$
>
>  So we can find the areas of the 4 circles (I do not assume that the two smallest ones are equal).
>
>  Then for any two intersecting circles we can measure the chords (we already have the points) and find the areas of the segments they form in both of the circles they are. It is possible since we already know the radiuses. Then simply subtract or add those area from the areas of corresponding circles as appropriate. Then we just add and subtract resulted four areas as appropriate.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly the solution I was looking for.